# Image button is click go to Servlet Without input any value

Tags: jsp, servlets, button, dao

My goal is when image button is click, it will go through servlet first then database object to retrieve data from database and the result will display in next jsp page.

Usually when I need to display data from database, I will ask user to input the value first and call out the servlet to retrieve data from database and then request dispatcher to the next page.

However, now I want the user to click the image instead of input any value. It can go to second.jsp but cannot display the data.

Is there something wrong with my codes.. or an image when click can't go to servlet?

Help will be appreciate. Thank you!

Below are my codes... :)

At  **web.xml**

```
 <servlet>
<display-name>PendingOrderServlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>PendingOrderServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>servlet.PendingOrderServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PendingOrderServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/PendingOrderServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

At **first.jsp**

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function doNextPage {
location.href = "PendingOrderServlet";}
</SCRIPT>
<img src="images/image.png" onclick="doNextPage();">
```

At **PendingOrderServlet**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    
        PendingOrderDAO pod = new PendingOrderDAO();
        request.setAttribute("order", pod.getPendingOrders());

        RequestDispatcher view = request
                .getRequestDispatcher("second.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
}
```

At **PendingOrderDAO**

```
public ArrayList getPendingOrders() {
    ArrayList<OrderBean> listpendingorder = new ArrayList<OrderBean>();
    try {
        currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        Statement statement = currentCon.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = statement
                .executeQuery("SELECT fborders.fbOrderId, fbmenu.fbMenuName, fborders.quantity, fborders.date, fborders.time, customer.custNRIC FROM fborders INNER JOIN fbmenu ON fborders.fbMenuId=fbmenu.fbMenuId INNER JOIN customer ON customer.custId=fborders.custId WHERE fborders.status='pending'");
        OrderBean OrderBean = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
            OrderBean = new OrderBean();
            OrderBean.setFbOrderId(rs.getInt("fbOrderId"));
            OrderBean.setFbMenuName(rs.getString("fbMenuName"));
            OrderBean.setQuantity(rs.getString("quantity"));
            OrderBean.setDate(rs.getString("date"));
            OrderBean.setTime(rs.getString("time"));
            OrderBean.setCustNRIC(rs.getString("custNRIC"));
            listpendingorder.add(OrderBean);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listpendingorder;
}
```

At **second.jsp**

```
    <table class="table tableshow">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ffOrder ID</th>
                            <th>Menu</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Time</th>
                            <th>Customer NRIC</th>
                            <th>.....</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                            <c:forEach items="${pendingorder}" var="order">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${pendingorder.getFbOrderId()}</td>
                        <td>${pendingorder.getFbMenuName()}</td>
                        <td>${pendingorder.getQuantity()}</td>
                        <td>${pendingorder.getDate()}</td>
                        <td>${pendingorder.getTime()}</td>
                        <td>${pendingorder.getCustNRIC()}</td>

                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>

                    </tbody>

                </table>
```

Comment: I don;t see anything wrong. What is your second.jsp?

Comment: @Loc Hi, I pasted all my codes including DAO and second.jsp. Is it correct to call my dao at doGET?

Comment: Of course. You can do whatever in doGet.

Comment: @Loc How about doPOST?

Comment: Yes. doPost the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Servlet. You passed attribute named 'order' but in JSP you used attribute named 'pendingorder'.

Servlet Code:

```
request.setAttribute("order", pod.getPendingOrders());
```

Correct JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${order}" var="item">
    <tr>
                    <td>${item.getFbOrderId()}</td>
                    <td>${item.getFbMenuName()}</td>
                    <td>${item.getQuantity()}</td>
                    <td>${item.getDate()}</td>
                    <td>${item.getTime()}</td>
                    <td>${item.getCustNRIC()}</td>

    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

NOTE: You can use ${item.fbOrderId} Instead of ${item.getFbOrderId()}

Comment: Silly me! Thank you! I did not see that. However, I am still unable to view the data. I already post a snapshot of my table.

Comment: unable to view data? You got exception or you see empty table?

Comment: I am really sorry. I am able to view it now.. Thank you for everything! :)

Comment: I just realize something. At first in second.jsp I put <td>${item.getFbOrderId()}</td>. It can display all the data, however all the data is 8. Suppose to be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.

Comment: When I use ${item.fbOrderId}, there is an error saying: Property 'fbOrderId' not readable on type int. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It is standard syntax of expression language. It doesn't care about property type. The important thing is your bean MUST have a GETTER named "getFbOrderId". You need to study EL. It is very important when developing JSP/Servlet app. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html